# JavaScript Regular Expression with special characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, replace

I have a list of words.

```
['incrediblé', 'incred!blé', '!ncrédiblé']
```

I have a list of strings.

```
[
'This is incrediblé! incrediblé2!',
'This is incred!blé! incred!blé2!',
'This is !ncrédiblé. !ncrédiblé2!']
```

I want to mask the words as they appear in the strings. It should not be greedy about it. That is, incredible in incredible2 should not be masked.

Following is the code that I have tried but fails to locate the words correctly.

```js
var words = ['incrediblé', 'incred!blé', '!ncrédiblé'];

var strings = [
  'This is incrediblé! incrediblé2!',
  'This is incred!blé! incred!blé2!',
  'This is !ncrédiblé. !ncrédiblé2!'
];

strings.forEach(string => {
  console.log('========================================');
  words.forEach(word => {
    const regex = new RegExp('\\b' + word + '\\b', 'gi');
    const masked = string.replace(regex, '*'.repeat(word.length));
    console.log(regex.test(string), '|', word, '|', masked);
  });
});
```

I want to maintain the word boundary. I don't intend to match the `!ncrédiblé` in the word `!ncrédiblé2`.

Comment: Use unambigous word boundaries, `const regex = new RegExp('(?<!\\w)' + word + '(?!\\w)', 'gi');`

Comment: This does not work with `ass`. As in, it matches `ass` in `assignment` and `assassination`.

Comment: Then use whitespace boundaries, `const regex = new RegExp('(?<!\\S)' + word + '(?!\\S)', 'gi');`. You need to rethink what a word is if that does not work for you either since that would mean you do not actually have "words" any longer.

Comment: Understood. Makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry but the spaces one does not work either. This requires some complex processing I believe.

Comment: Well, you probably want to "add" `!` to the word chars (count `!` as a word char). Try `const regex = new RegExp('(?<![\\w!])' + word + '(?![\\w!])', 'gi');`